# Click on both nested <li>s

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day. I've searched high and low. Found nothing.

I have this structure:

```
<ul class='c1'>
  <li>
AAA
    <ul class='c2'>
      <li>
BBB
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And jquery handler:

```
$('.c1>li').bind('dblclick',function() {
    alert('a')
});
$('.c2>li').bind('dblclick',function() {
    alert('b')
});
```

But when i click C2's li i get both messages instead of just 'b'.
    event.stopPropagation() cant solve the problem

Thank you.

Comment: "event.stopPropagation() cant solve the problem"
uhm... yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/ot9m6fnn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would also need to use event as parameter in function for using with stopPropagation:

```
$('.c2>li').bind('dblclick',function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation() 
   alert('b')
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can return `false` after a statement

```
$('.c1>li').bind('dblclick', function() {
    alert('a');
    return false;
});

$('.c2>li').bind('dblclick', function() {
    alert('b');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
$( "ul.c1 li" ).children().dblclick(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    alert("a");
})

$( "ul.c2 li" ).children().dblclick(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("b");
})
```

Comment: What did you change the code from double-click to click?

Comment: Answer to second question: I see now you are getting obvious serial up-votes on all your answers (regardless of how correct they are). That will backfire very quickly on SO. I suggest you stop cheating ASAP and try earn the points instead :)

Comment: Even with the edit this is still a poor answer, adding event handlers to  far more elements than required. Suggest you try out the accepted answer and figure out why that works with less code.